# 10M: How will SO ensure that it awards the same number of men's shirts as women's shirts?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

**This is not about the mechanics of obtaining people's postal addresses!!!** The "how will we get our shirts" question does ***NOT*** contain an answer to this question! Sheesh!

---

OK, so they want to give away 50 men's shirts and 50 women's shirts. I'm guessing StackOverflow has a lot more men than women. Does that mean that men have a lower chance of winning? How do the contest organizers even figure out which pool a user belongs in? What about those people who prefer to wear the opposite gender's clothing? (For example, I'm a girl, but I prefer men's t-shirts, because the ladies styles are always too short.) What about sizes? Do they have a certain number in each size and type, and they keep trying to give them away until they find someone who wears that particular gender and size? I'm confuzzled.

(Wouldn't it be better, and more straightforward, to give away 100 shirts to 100 random people, and then figure out what type and size of shirt each winner wants?)

Note to the duplicate-voters: please read more carefully. I'm not asking about how SO plans to find out where the winners live. I'm asking how they plan to make sure they award the same number of men's shirts as women's shirts.

Comment: Complaining aside, I do actually wonder how they will differentiate male and female accounts. Some people would be easy enough... but a lot people have generic pseudonyms.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, no, that's just asking how SO is supposed to know our address. I'm asking how they plan to make sure they give away the same number of men's shirts as women's shirts. Because stuff like this is so much more important than the work I'm supposed to be doing. You know? :)

Comment: @Martha no no, every week they will select 50 winners and send 2 shirts to each winner! There :P

Comment: What *is* it with people who can't actually read, but can somehow muster the ability to hit the "close" button? The ***ONLY*** thing the other question has in common with this one is that it, too, is about the 10M questions milestone.

Comment: @laune what about the people in third world countries whose livelihoods depend on making tshirts?

Comment: On the other hand, a refugee might win. A female refugee would be even cooler.

Comment: _"(Wouldn't it be better, and more straightforward, to give away 100 shirts to 100 random people, and then figure out what type and size of shirt each winner wants?)"_ YES! This is the only fair and non-discriminatory way to do it. None of this 50% of them 50% of them bollocks. It makes me sick. And ashamed. I know SE means well (as do the millions of other firms doing the same thing) but introducing discrimination is literally the worst possible way to fight discrimination.

Comment: @samgak On the few thou SO is going to order for this jubilee? How much of that will actually go to the factory worker in Bangladesh or wherever it is? - But I was more taken aback by the frantic discussion about equal-gendering the shirts (or obtaining the delivery adress and some such trifles). As if this would be the greatest of our worries. Tchak.

Comment: Well @Martha, if they'll give t-shirts asking [whoeverwins] what kind they want and the number is fixed (50M/50F), even whishing you to win, as a man I can say **THANKS!** for stealing a man t-shirt and one of the little chanches I have to win!! ...On the other side a girl will tank you for giving her one more chance to win a (easyertowin) glir t-shirt. (...just kidding!) **;)**

Comment: Why should they worry about awarding the same number of tshirts to men and women? I can't see a problem if they gave away more womens tshirts, hopefully it might encourage more women to use stack exchanges as they'd have a higher chance of winning/getting a tshirt

Comment: I didn't expect that there must be a difference between a tshirt for men and a tshirt for women - I mean, it's a tshirt, I can understand "tshirt for women which would look weird on a man" but not at all "tshirt for men which would look weird on a woman" - but regardless, I recently understood that what makes you a man or a woman is not anything physical but simply whether you currently identify as a man or as a woman, so the only non-sexist, politically correct criterium to assign the tshirts is to ask each single recipient directly whether he/she is a man or a woman.

Comment: It's the spiders that are really being discriminated against here.

Comment: I love *confuzzled*. I'll steal it, I wish I could +2 :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I wish I could remember who/where I stole *confuzzled* from. I'm *pretty* sure I didn't make it up myself. I think. :)

Comment: @Martha I've heard it elsewhere, it seems to just be an underused portmanteau, and as such was probably invented by more than one person.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Presumably if they pick you they'll ask you the following questions:

1. What style T-shirt would you like.
2. What size T-shirt would you like.
3. Where would you like the T-shirt sent.

There's no way that they can know whether you are male or female from your profile as that information is not collected. They could try to guess from your user name and/or profile picture but that's pretty much guaranteed to fail.

I'm guessing the 50/50 thing is to show that Stack Exchange encourages women in tech. And I'm also guessing that there are more women on Stack Overflow than is evident from user names etc. (though I have no evidence to back this up).

I also suspect that the number of shirts isn't fixed in stone and there may be some leeway on this.

Comment: So, basically, the contest works exactly how I described in my "wouldn't it be better" parenthetical, you're just not advertising it that way. Got it, thanks! :)

Comment: There is likely more women than is evident from usernames but still no where near 50%... Actually, there is some data from the last [survey](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-gender). 92.1% male (self-reported but should be a fairly good sample data). It's their tshirts, so I'm happy for them to give them to whoever they see fit though.

Comment: @Martha - I wouldn't say that for sure - I'm not an employee. But given that SE doesn't ask your gender when you sign up they'll have to do *something* like I describe.

Comment: That answers the question. But unfortunately, while I thank for the initiative, considering the numbers of (active) people on the site (a lot), and the number of t-shirts allocated (a few), the probability to have to worry about size and gender of a t-shirt is very small.

Comment: If there are 9 males for every 1 female, then that means there will statistically be 450 male t-shirts given away and 50 female t-shirts. Unless after 50 male t-shirts are given away, they inform the "winner" that they only really get a t-shirt if they want a female t-shirt. So are they going to reject 400 winners that were "winners" but turns out they won't be receiving a shirt? Hmm. I guess that is if it's randomly picked which users are winners set on criteria that's not gender based. But employee could pick female winners manually to help avoid such "you won, but you're a guy, so jk" stuff

Comment: I do hope this is the case, because I would prefer a men's shirt. Women's generic shirts fit weird on me.

Comment: @Martha: I don't know why but a man might be allowed to get women's T-shirt (as a gift, punishment for a kid, sister, SO, etc).

Comment: Haha, based on the rules of the competition they indeed should just be sending women shirts to men xD . It would definitely solve the entire problem. But honestly, what a terrible initiative to set the number of available shirts without consideration of their audience. I mean, I don't care much, because the chance of winning is far too small either way, but it does show a certain amount of out of touch-ness with your public (especially as slicedtoad correctly point out that SO could have known this).

Comment: so i'm thinking there is a possibility giving all the shirts to only males or females..

Answer (score 7):

As one of the lucky winners, I can tell you that I got a mail from Abby Miller (Abby Hairboat) with a link. In the link, it was asked what type of T-shirt I wanted, using a combobox.

We may conclude that SO does not know or guess your sex beforehand; they simply ask for the data when they need it, and not earlier.

So there's not really a 50/50 thing going on. And if you prefer a T-shirt meant for the other sex, you can just ask that.

Comment: Well, you did not mention #SOreadytohelp in  your profile still you won? how? or you removed after getting t shirt?

Comment: @Leothelion You can put it on your profile, or use it on Twitter. I used Twitter: https://twitter.com/s_l_barth/status/634376804153823232 .

Comment: oopps yup i forget..my bad..sry

Comment: @Leothelion No prob, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Am I off base in seeing a much simpler solution?

Let people self-identify (privately), then select 50 from each pool.

Comment: You must be a project manager :)

Comment: Hey, could you show me how to add this #SOreadytohelp to my Profile

Comment: @AndreaLigios - I keep coming back to your response and still don't understand it; could you explain?

Comment: @joshfindit don't worry it's just a joke. The meaning is: you see a simple solution where actually the solution is not simple nor even practicable at all, for many reasons, and [this is usually a PM behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg). The biggest fail of your solution is that people that has been extracted among million of users, get contacted, then might not win anything because of being in the wrong gender pool (quite frustrating, uh ?), and this could lead to thousands of rejects before populating both pools. And you have to trust them, and... see it ? Not viable. Cheers

Comment: @AndreaLigios Ahh, I understand. My intent wasn't to oversimplify or gloss over difficult logistics. Instead the proposed solution came from the perspective of try to meet the 50/50 split while keeping the sensitive issue of gender identity as the top priority.
Obviously we're on the tail end of this and it turns out the 50/50 split wasn't really a requirement, which means my answer wasn't a good fit either way.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks for the explanation, and the video reference.